# what is the element face in ply file format

Tags: c++, opengl

I am writing a code to read and draw ply file format in opengl (c++).
I used `glVertex3d` function for vertex element. and now i couldn't understand that what's the `element face` in ply files?? is this for color? any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Faces are polygons.  After reading the vertices start reading the faces.  Each face line starts with the number of vertices in the polygon.  Then that number of 0-offset polygon vertex indices follow.

Say you read the vertices into a vector of structs with x, y, z members (say).  Also read the face indices into a struct.

```
for (int f = 0; f < num_faces; ++f)
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      for (int i = 0; i < face[f].num_vertices; ++i)
      {
        glVertex3f(face[f].vertex[i].x,face[f].vertex[i].y, face[f].vertex[i].z);
      }
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Thank you emser. you use `glVertex3f` for drawing vertices. ok. i am looking for a opengl function like `glVertex3f` for drawing faces. thanks a lot

Comment: @user1972067: OpenGL doesn't think in "faces", and there's no ready to use function for it. You must loop over the faces yourself. emser's answer is a bit outdated, as it uses the immediate mode. The better solution would be to unroll the data in the PLY file into a set of vertex attribute arrays and matching index arrays.

Comment: @user1972067 Thanks, i know I'm back a few versions of the rd&blue books ;-).  i haven't used raw openGL in a while.  I use open Inventor which uses a retained mode openGL.  You construct face sets and Coordinate sets with arrays.  Coin3D is a good Free implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The element faces describes how many faces (polygon) there are in all of the ply files.

```
ply
format ascii 1.0           { ascii/binary, format version number }
comment made by Greg Turk  { comments keyword specified, like all lines }
comment this file is a cube
element vertex 8           { define "vertex" element, 8 of them in file }
property float x           { vertex contains float "x" coordinate }
property float y           { y coordinate is also a vertex property }
property float z           { z coordinate, too }
element face 6             { there are 6 "face" elements in the file }
property list uchar int vertex_index { "vertex_indices" is a list of ints }
end_header                 { delimits the end of the header }
0 0 0                      { start of vertex list }
0 0 1
0 1 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 0
4 0 1 2 3                  { start of face list }
4 7 6 5 4
4 0 4 5 1
4 1 5 6 2
4 2 6 7 3
4 3 7 4 0
```

If you take a look at where the face list starts and you count to the end, then you should count 6. And the element faces also says 6 to confirm it.

---

The ply file above was shamefully stolen from http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/

Comment: thanks. What should i do for drawing the face elements? I used this `glVertex3d` for vertex elements but for face elements i don't know

Comment: @user1972067 GL is not my forty (more of Direct3D) but I would check this link for how to dry a ply file in OpenGL http://openglsamples.sourceforge.net/files/glut_ply.cpp

Comment: annoyingly enought, that exampel crashes in meshlab, unexpected EOF, i am strugging to find examples that work in meshlab

Comment: @com.prehensible: I know it is late, but for the sake of completeness: The descriptions in this example are invalid code. `{ foo bar }` is not part of the PLY format. So if these descriptions are removed the file can be opened in MeshLab.

Answer (score 0):

element is a triangle index, because the above example didn't work in meshlab EOF, here is another example:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment VCGLIB generated
element vertex 8
property float x
property float y
property float z
property float nx
property float ny
property float nz
element face 12
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
-1 24 4.5 -1.570796 1.570796 1.570796 
0 21 4.5 1.570796 -1.570796 1.570796 
0 24 4.5 1.570796 1.570796 1.570796 
-1 21 4.5 -1.570796 -1.570796 1.570796 
-1 21 2.5 -1.570796 -1.570796 -1.570796 
0 24 2.5 1.570796 1.570796 -1.570796 
0 21 2.5 1.570796 -1.570796 -1.570796 
-1 24 2.5 -1.570796 1.570796 -1.570796 
3 0 1 2 
3 1 0 3 
3 4 5 6 
3 5 4 7 
3 4 1 3 
3 1 4 6 
3 1 5 2 
3 5 1 6 
3 5 0 2 
3 0 5 7 
3 4 0 7 
3 0 4 3
```